# Customizing documentation from workbench?

Tags: documentation, workbench, document-creation

The documentation generator is working now for me, but I'm hoping someone knows how to customize the html generation in any of the following ways:

1. Is there a way to keep input cells as text (instead of bitmaps) or at least enable copy-code-to-clipboard?
2. Is there a way to include custom cell styles in the generated html?
3. Keep syntax highlighting for code and input cells?
4. Default to the 'Standard' css templates (instead of 'Minimal')?

Comment: I think that the transformation is done by the Transmogrify package.  Launch Mathematica from the Workbench and use ``FindFile["Transmogrify`"]`` to find its location within `Eclipse.app`.  There is some (unbuilt but useful) documentation that comes with the package (so you don't have to figure everything out by reading the source).  I don't know the answer to any of your questions, but I think the best start is to examine this package first.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the hint, it looks like Transmogrify` can convert notebooks to an XML object using it's XMLTransform approach. But what happens after that to convert the xml to html?

Comment: I don't know. To be honest, I didn't look at the package in detail, but I really thought it was the key to the solution.  Maybe it isn't ...  If you figure it out, let us know. I'm interested, but have no time to look at it.